# how to find out ExecuteScalar() is dbnull

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, dbnull, executescalar

How do I check to see if the result of `ExecuteScalar()` has no data? Checking if it is nothing does not work.

My code:

```
Dim cmdCode As New OracleCommand
cmdCode.Connection = sgcnn
cmdCode.CommandText = "select max(SUBSTR(client_code,4,7)) from CLIENT_INFO where (client_code Like '%' || :SysUser || '%') "
cmdCode.Parameters.Add("@SysUser", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = strMessage

'Dim sqlResult As Object = cmdCode.ExecuteScalar()
'If sqlResult Is Nothing Then
'    ' No result found
'    strMessage.Append("0001")
'    txtClientCode.Text = strMessage.ToString
'Else
'    'result found
'    Dim newProdID As Int32 = 0
'    newProdID = Convert.ToInt32(cmdCode.ExecuteScalar())
'    newProdID = newProdID + 1
'    strMessage.Append(newProdID.ToString("0000"))
'    txtClientCode.Text = strMessage.ToString
'End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        If IsDBNull(cmdCode.ExecuteScalar()) Then
        '    ' No result found
        '    strMessage.Append("0001")
        '    txtClientCode.Text = ""
    Else
        '    'result found
        '    Dim newProdID As Int32 = 0
        '    newProdID = Convert.ToInt32(cmdCode.ExecuteScalar())
        '    newProdID = newProdID + 1
        '    strMessage.Append(newProdID.ToString("0000"))
        '    txtClientCode.Text = strMessage.ToString
    End If
```

Answer (score 2):

```
If sqlResult Is DBNull.Value Then
```

Once you've established that it's not NULL though, don't go and call `ExecuteScalar` again.  You've already got the result so use it.  Also, it already is an `Integer` so there's no need to convert.  Just cast:

```
Dim newProdID = CInt(sqlResult) + 1
```

Comment: thanx , jmcilhinney